# Environment handling in soapUI

Tags: soapui

I was trying to use environment feature which is available in Soapui 4.5 pro and it is not working :( Anyone tried this before or is there any other way to achieve this? For me, each environment will have different DB connections and API end points. Help much appreciated.

http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/environment-handling-in-soapui.html

Comment: I have tested it and it worked fine. You should ask SoapUI support since you are a SoapUI Pro user.

Comment: Yes, i posted it in SoapUI support forum and it seems like many are facing this issue. BTW: Are you using nightly build or stable version?

Comment: Thanks minisu. I have solved this issue by passing value from Jenkins to SoapUI and then i replaced the API end point using this value. however the environment set up didn't work for me. So now my API end point URL will be something like this : ${#Project#API_URL} where API_URL is a project level custom variable. Let me know if you have any doubts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a '**Load script**' for the project:
[image] This script always executes when you run soapui or testrunner and gets the endpoint *(or some other parameter e.g. DB connection)* from the config file.

Script code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner

def utils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

// load config file
def pathConfig = utils.projectPath + "/<path to your project>/config/"
def config = new java.util.Properties()
config.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(pathConfig + "config.ini"))

// set the project endpoint from the config
props = project
props.setPropertyValue("Env", config.getProperty("endpoint"))

log.info "Running test for: " + config.getProperty("endpoint");
```

As you can see the script puts your endpoint into the custom project variable **Env**. So in all your requests you should use the endpoint **http://${#Project#Env}**.

Config file:

```
endpoint = dev.mysite.com
```

Solution is also available for **non pro version**

Answer (score 0):

To get DB connection, you can use GroovyUtilsPro Class, https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/pro/com/eviware/soapui/support/GroovyUtilsPro.html

eg.

```
def utils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtilsPro(context)\
def conn = utils.getJdbcConnection("{the Name of your JDBC Connections in Environments}")
```

this is for soapUI pro only. 
I am still looking for how get services endpoint from 'Environments' setting.